# Is it possible to bind control visibility to the content? (XAML)

Tags: xaml, binding, visibility

I created a result view for a class, calculating some math-stuff. According to the values, set by the user, there are some of the results returning 0 or "". So some of the Controls bound to this empty properties are also empty. Thats some kind of ugly, because calculating with these Values will never contain such a result. So I don't want to show this control. 
Is it possible, not to show this control if the property it is bound to is empty?

Greetings from Germany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind `Value` to element Visibility property with help of `Converter` that will provide your logic.

Comment: Came to the same Solution on my own. But thak you anyways :)